# Strange behaviour when toggling filtered results in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dom-events

I have a list of elements `{name: 'bla', done:false}`, which is being filtered by `done` property to display.

```
[_] element1
[_] element2
```

When I click on a checkbox, the property `done` is changed and therefore this element disappears. The strange thing is that when I click on the first element, it disappears and the second element is shown but with a checkbox checked!

```
[v] element2
```

Note - the element is visible (it's OK), but somehow checked (not OK).

How to avoid this? I don't want a check without a click. I don't even know, what words to google, such a weird case :)

Working example of a bug - [try to check first filtered element](https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/76oqt1dk/13/). The other problem is that it works correct as a snippet here in SO, but goes wrong in *jsfiddle* (and my app).

**Note: below you can see desired behaviour. Fiddle for wrong.**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed:{
   todosfiltered: function(){
   return this.todos.filter(function(elem){
   return !elem.done;
   });
   },
  },
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, tip:true },
      { text: "Learn Vue2", done: false, tip:false, },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true, tip:false },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true, tip:false }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <h2>
  filtered elements:
  </h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(todo, key) in todosfiltered">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }} <span v-if="todo.tip">&lt;-- click this checbox</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's being caused by missing a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) property on the element being looped over.  Always include a key to prevent issues like this, and make sure that key is unique.

I'm using `todo.text` here, but if text is not unique, you may run into the same rendering errors.  Instead, you may want to add an `id` property to differentiate them.

```
<h2>
  filtered elements:
  </h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todosfiltered" :key="todo.text">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }} <span v-if="todo.tip">&lt;-- click this checbox</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

And lastly, the index of the for loop may be used, but this is less than optimal due to the way that Vuejs handles [rerendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).  When using an index, removing an element from the list will cause the index of all elements after it to change, forcing a rerender on all of them.  This doesn't matter for smaller sets of data, but can have an impact on larger lists.

Comment: It's hard to say.  It could be the Vue version, or how Stack Overflow wraps the code snippet.  As a general rule, always include it to prevent any undefined behaviour, and only omit it if you have a very compelling reason to.